# Express your answer using factorial notation

Tags: calculus

If $ f(x) = \frac{x^{46} + x^{45} + 2}{1 + x} $, calculate $ f^{(46)}(3) $. (Express your answer using factorial notation.)

I simplificated the function :  $(3^{45}+ \frac{1}{2} )^{46} $  and i don't know how to express this answer using factorial notation give me a hint. I think that I must use BINOMIAL formula but show me the next step

Comment: How did you obtain the expression that you wrote? ("I simplified the function")

Comment: $ (f(3))^{46} = (\frac{3^{46} +  3^{45} + 2}{1 + 3})^{46} $

Comment: Hmm ... I think the notation $f^{(46)}$ refers to the fourty-sixth **derivative** of the function. What do you think?

Comment: Can you try applying the binomial formula for $n$-th derivative $$(fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}$$ ([source](https://www.lucaswillems.com/en/articles/6/nth-derivative-of-product)) and show us your work?

Comment: (Formula for the Derivative of the Product of several Functions)}\\
Let $ f_1 , f_2 , \dots , f_n $ be differentiable functions at a number $x $. Then
$$ (f_1 f_2 \dots f_n)^{'} (x) = f_1^{'} (x)f_2 (x) \dots f_n (x) + $$
$$ + f_1(x) f_2 ^{'} (x) f_3(x) \dots f_n (x) + \cdots + f_1(x) f_2 (x) \dots f_{n-1} (x) f_n ^{'} (x) . $$ and use this formul?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @Matti.P's explanation that $f^{(n)}(x)$ means $\tfrac{d^nf}{dx^n}$, note $\frac{x^{46}+x^{45}+2}{1+x}=x^{45}+\frac{2}{1+x}$, so$$f^{(46)}(x)=2\tfrac{d^{46}}{dx^{46}}\tfrac{1}{1+x}=\tfrac{46!2}{(1+x)^{47}}$$(you may need to prove by induction that $\tfrac{d^n}{dx^n}\tfrac{1}{1+x}=\tfrac{n!(-1)^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$ if the result is unfamiliar). Hence $f^{(46)}(3)=\tfrac{46!}{2^{93}}$.